# Argument of type Promise<MemberEntityVM[]> is not assignable to parameter of type SetStateAction<MemberEntityVM[]>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I want to show a list of members of Github, filtered by organization (for instance, members of Github which are employees of Microsoft). I am using React + TS. So, I have the following `API Model` (the interface of the JSON data that I receive after doing the call to the GitHub API):

```
export interface MemberEntityApi {
    login: string;
    id: number;
    node_id: string;
    avatar_url: string;
    gravatar_id: string;
    url: string;
    html_url: string;
    followers_url: string;
    following_url: string;
    gists_url: string;
    starred_url: string;
    subscriptions_url: string;
    organizations_url: string;
    repos_url: string;
    events_url: string;
    received_events_url: string;
    type: string;
    site_admin: string;
}
```

But I dont wanna use so much information, so I will create a `ViewModel` (just with the information I want to use). Here my `ViewModel`:

```
export interface MemberEntityVM {
    id: number;
    login: string;
    avatar_url: string;
}
```

Here my call to the API:

```
export const getMembers = (organization: string, perpage, page): Promise<MemberEntityApi[]> => {
    return fetch(`https://api.github.com/orgs/${organization}/members?per_page=${perpage}&page=${page}`)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                const data = response.json();
                return data;
            } else {
                throw new Error(response.statusText)
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

Here my mapper function:

```
export const mapMemberEntityFromAPIModelToVM = (data: MemberEntityApi[]): MemberEntityVM[] => {
    return data.map((data) => {
        return {
            id: data.id,
            login: data.login,
            avatar_url: data.avatar_url
        }
    })
}
```

So, in my component, the problem is the following one:

```
const [members, setMembers] = React.useState<MemberEntityVM[]>([]);
const [organization, setOrganization] = React.useState<string>("Microsoft");

    useEffect(() => {
        const membersVM = getMembers(organization, perpage, page)
            .then((data) => mapMemberEntityFromAPIModelToVM(data));
        console.log("membersVM", membersVM);
        setMembers(membersVM);
        console.log("members", members);
    }, [])
```

This sentence `console.log("membersVM", membersVM);` is showing a response with an array of 3 members of a given organization (that is correct, since I just want to show 3 members per page) but this sentence `console.log("members", members);` shows an empty array. That means `setMembers(membersVM);` is not working. But I dont understand why. I am receiving the following mistake: `"Argument of type Promise<MemberEntityVM[]> is not assignable to parameter of type SetStateAction<MemberEntityVM[]>"` in the line I do `setMembers(membersVM);`. I dont understand this error message since `membersVM` has the following interface `MemberEntityVM[]` and the type of `useState` is the following one: `React.useState<MemberEntityVM[]>`. Where am I committing the mistake? Thanks in advance, kind regards.

Comment: `getMembers` returns a promise. You need to use `await` to wait for it to resolve before attempting to use the value it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getMembers(..).then(..)` returns a promise of the mapped members, you will need to either `await` the value or deal with it in the `then` handler. Since `useEffect` does not allow an asynchronous function as its argument, the easiest solution is to call `setMembers` in the existing `then` handler:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getMembers(organization, perpage, page)
    .then((data) => {
      const membersVM = mapMemberEntityFromAPIModelToVM(data);
      console.log("membersVM", membersVM);
      setMembers(membersVM);
      console.log("members", members);
    });
}, [])
```

If you do wish to use async/await, you can declare a local async function `fetchMembers`, and immediately call it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchMembers = async () => {
    const data = await getMembers(organization, perpage, page);
    const membersVM = mapMemberEntityFromAPIModelToVM(data);
    console.log('membersVM', membersVM);
    setMembers(membersVM);
    console.log('members', members);
  }
  fetchMembers();
}, [])
```